# Sequelize, Validate length of field with blank value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) as ORM with express.

In [Sequelize Model](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/), their is field that accepts the null value. I want to validate this field by defining the length of the input with `len` if any value is provided.

Code:

```
field: {
  type: DataTypes.TEXT,
  allowNull: true,
  validate: {
    len: {
      args: [50, 200],
      msg: 'Please provide field within 50 to 200 characters.'
    }
  }
}
```

But, Sequelize throw error when field is empty. So, How do i allow the empty value, and just validate only when value is provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this `notEmpty: false` ?

```
field: {
  type: DataTypes.TEXT,
  allowNull: true,
  validate: {
    notEmpty: false,
    len: {
      args: [50, 200],
      msg: 'Please provide field within 50 to 200 characters.'
    }
  }
}
```